# Embed IPB forums to wordpress page

Tags: forms, embed

I have a community that is really forum driven, and after messing with most major content management systems, I've really liked Wordpress for Its front news pages/blog posts.

The issue that I'm facing, ( I've faced this issue with all CMS's ) is that I want an embedded forums page. I don't want my forums in an iFrame, in a separate page that's skinned to look similar to my site, I want the forum embedded on the actual wordpress page.

The forum software I use is IBP, Invision Power Board

I know of a site doing exactly this: http://www.guildwars2guru.com/ - They're using Wordpress and IP.Board, and it looks great!

Is something like this possible without doing custom development? I already have the users bridged, I just need the forums to be displayed on a wordpress page in a presentable manner.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: The end result is probably going to involve a hefty amount of theming of IBP, which isn't something people here are likely to know about ( and isn't in the scope of this stack )

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to modify your IBP theme to bootstrap WordPress, and display the header and footer, [you can do this by following this Codex article here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

This will load the WordPress environment and allow you to use WordPress functions:

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Modify the require statement as necessary to match your folder structure.

Beyond that however, you'll need to use WordPress functions inside your IBP forums theme. How you do this is not something within the scope of this site or my knowledge and requires IBP people with IBP knowledge, as this isn't the place to discuss IBP theming.

Answer (score 0):

That site is not using WordPress. The integration is tight on that site because they're using IP.Content (from the same company that makes IP.Board).

Comment: I actually emailed the support, they're using Wordpress, they couldn't tell me their solution, as it was in house, or custom made.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that they are using WordPress on that site